# how to center align a word with bold and underline

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting

I need to center align a word with bold and underlines.

I've tried with `\textbf` and `\centerline` in all possible combinations but no use.

I am using `\documentclass[12pt]{report}` for my report doc.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  You'll want to use the `soul` package, but *please* consider the use of logical markup.  Are you trying to mark sections in a special way (perhaps in accordance with APA)?  It would be much better to just change such a command to do what you need.  It would also help to *see* what you've tried; please edit that into your question and mark it as code by selecting it and clicking the `{}` above the editor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following contains a number of solutions. Please pick up the  one you want.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}

\centerline{I need to center align a \uline{\bfseries word} with bold and underlines.}

\bigskip

\begin{center}
  I need to center align a\\
  \uline{\bfseries word}\\
  with bold and underlines.
\end{center}


\bigskip

I need to center align a 

\centerline{\uline{\bfseries word}}

with bold and underlines.

\end{document}
```

Here is the output.

[image]